# Replace all PNGs with GIFs in jquery?

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to replace all PNGs across the board with GIFs using jquery? How would I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean just changing the extension of each image src, or do you mean converting a PNG to GIF in jQuery? Though I'd wonder why you want this way, instead of converting GIFs to PNGs...

Comment: If you consider only `img` tags it is easy to replace the `src` property but if you want to handle images in external css stylesheets things might get tougher.

Comment: I was just after changing the string, the answer below answered my question exactly :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have the images as gifs already?

If you do, it will be as easy as doing something like:

```
$('img').each(function() {
     var src = $(this).attr("src").replace(".png", ".gif");
     $(this).attr("src", src);
});
```

This will go through all the img tags, and replace the path with it's own path, but with the gif extension instead of png

Let me know if that helps you.

Comment: What about `<img src="groupngrope.jpg"/>`? You should at least add the dot (and if you're a perfectionist, a `$|\?` and convert it to an regexp).

Comment: Thought about the regexp (my preferred choice normally), but wanted to give him a simple example, so he could understand. the groupngroup is a valid thing though. Have already updated my code to use a .

+1 for you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Are all PNGs referenced as '.png'? If not, it isn't possible with JS alone (see [Mozilla's doc on the Image object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Image): No property re. the mime type).

Else try mplacona's solution.

Edit: To give an example: This URL

```
http://www.w3.org/Icons/valid-html40
```

leads to an image, but you cannot guess, which format it is. You can explicitly request

```
http://www.w3.org/Icons/valid-html40.gif
```

or

```
http://www.w3.org/Icons/valid-html40.png
```

but, without extension, the server decides, what it sends, and the client (JavaScript, that is) has no means to decide what will come.